# Third-party API won't work after deployment

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sendgrid

I have built and deployed a basic portfolio website to Heroku. In this app, I use a third-party API for sending emails (sendgrid) in the contact form. When I was running my app locally on localhost:3000, the API was working as anticiapted and would send me emails. However, once I deployed my app to Heroku, I recieve [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jekJa.png).  When I run `heroku logs --tail` in my terminal, I get  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt2Qc.png).

Inexcplicably, the API has now stopped working when I run it locally as well. I see error 503 means network error so I am somehow not making a request to the server? The only thing I have changed that I could think would break it is:

- I removed the react router to change pages and instead used react-scroll. Maybe this messed with the routes I use in my `contact.js` file to send the object to sendgird?
- I moved my API key to `.env` rather than storing it in my global environmental variables. I've used dotenv to transpile this but maybe i went wrong somewhere? When I run `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY)`, it logs the correct key.

This is where I call the API from the contact.js form:

```js
  emailApi = () => {
    let sendgridObj = {
      to: 'caseyclinga@gmail.com',
      from: this.state.from,
      subject: this.state.subject,
      text: this.state.text
    }
    this.resetState();
    axios.post('/', sendgridObj)
      .then(res => console.log(`CONTACT.JS RESPONSE: ${res}`))
      .catch(err => console.log(`CONTACT.JS ERROR: ${err}`));
  }
```

This is the server.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const SgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();


SgMail.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY);

//Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Serve static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  //Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) 
    SgMail.send(req.body)
    .then(res => console.log(`SERVER.JS RESPONSE: ${res}`))
    .catch(err => console.log(`SERVER.JS ERROR: ${err}`));
  });

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Here is my deployed site: https://still-sands-49669.herokuapp.com/
Here is my code: https://github.com/caseycling/portfolio

Comment: Sounds very much like a hickup with the API key env variable

Comment: Does sendgrid not provide a message with the 503 code?

Comment: All it says is network error